# Team foundation Build errors on RestSharp and NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I can build my branch locally without any problem but when I try to build in via team foundation i get 2 errors.  The errors are generated on a project i recently added to the solution.

The errors are:

`EnvoyClient.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [c:\TF-Agents\Agent2017-002\_work\2\s\System\Envoy.Connector\Envoy.Connector.csproj]`

`EnvoyClient.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [c:\TF-Agents\Agent2017-002\_work\2\s\System\Envoy.Connector\Envoy.Connector.csproj]`

I have tried to remove the nuget packages and re-adding them in my local branch, and then pull requesting them again to the branch i want to build on tf-server, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a step in your build process to restore the NuGet packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the nuget packages were not being loaded in, because this project was not part of the solution

IIRC building this different solution was setup because we have a sync that does not need all the projects on the side that our main solution has. And building the big solution takes over 10 minutes. So we created a smaller solution just for the sync. And my nuget packages were loaded correctly, but because that project was missing he did not load them, and the subsequent build failed. But the restore nuget packages step worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

***Update from OP:***

So the problem was the nuget packages were not being loaded in, because this project was not part of the solution.

I had to add my new project (with these 2 references) to that solution and then it builded perfectly.

---

> EnvoyClient.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

For this kind of issue,  if your local build is successful and just the TFS build is failing then it is usually due to dll reference path issue. Make sure that the Dll is **referenced as a relative path** in the project file (.csproj).

To add a relative reference in a separate directory, do the following:

Add the reference in Visual Studio by right clicking the project in Solution Explorer and selecting Add Reference.

Find the *.csproj where this reference exist and open it in a text editor. Lets say your .csproj location is c:\tfs_get\sources\myfolder\myproject\myproj.csproj

Edit the < HintPath > to be equal to

```
..\\..\assembly\xxx.dll
```

Also as Daniel suggested, please double check your build process if there included a NuGet restore step.

Besides, you should keep your build server environment the same with your local environment. Please double check this. For trouble shooting, you could try to remote to that tfs build agent manually run your build on it.

Comment: I did have a nuget restore step which passed without any problems.  I did not set up this tfs build thing, so i didn't notice this build profile was building a different solution.  I had to add my new project (with these 2 references) to that solution and then it builded perfectly.

So the problem was the nuget packages were not being loaded in, because this project was not part of the solution

Comment: @ThierryVerhaegen Thanks for your kindly update. To be honest, building a different solution is not a common  scenario. We couldn't come up with it.  But just as we pointed out and the error indicated, your nuget packages were not loaded properly. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer, which will also helps others in the community.

Comment: IIRC building this different solution was setup because we have a sync that does not need all the projects on the side that our main solution has.  And building the big solution takes over 10 minutes.  So we created a smaller solution just for the sync.

And my nuget packages were loaded correctly, but because that project was missing he did not load them, and the subsequent build failed.  But the restore nuget packages step worked like a charm.  So i'm afraid this comment did not really put me in the right direction, there wasn't a light bulb that went off

Comment: @ThierryVerhaegen Thanks for the detail explanation and analysis. Always better when you fix it yourself; as you understand how it works!:)  Would you mind to move your comment and solution to a new reply and then mark your own reply as answer. Which will helps others in the community, in case they got stuck with the similar issue. Then they could quickly figure out it based on your experience.